# How to parse Json data and pass them on another activity?

Tags: java, android, json

I have a php file that has this output in Json format.

```
{"user":{"id":"2","name":"aris","surname":"roumeliotis","expire_memb":"201812-15","program":"chest_workout"}
,"exercise1":
{"name":"chest_exercise_name_1",
"gif":"\/img\/ex\/ex_1",
"place":"machine 18",
"muscle_team":"chest"}

,"exercise2":
{"name":"chest_exercise_name_2",
"gif":"\/img\/ex\/ex_2",
"place":"machine 20",
"muscle_team":"chest"}
```

It means that the user with the id 2 has 2 exercises in his gym program.
I know how to parse the data(using Volley library) but I am having trouble to send them to another activity using intent since exercise1 and exercise2 have the same key names.

The exercises number may differ for each user so that means that the php file output is dynamic and may have many exercises for a user.
I can pass the user data to another activity since they are unique but i cant pass the exercises data. I tried to use arrays but that didn't work. A code sample starting from the creation of a `JSONobject` till the `getIntent()` of the other activity would be appreciated.

The whole point for this is to use the exercise data to start a for() in the other activity and show the data in dynamically created TextViews assuming i know the number of the exercises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, it is best to send the whole json to another activity, and parse it again on new activity as per need.

Create Activity like this:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(this,AnotherActivtiy.class);
intent.putExtra("json",json);
```

Get the json like this:

```
if(getIntent().getExtras()!=null)
    String json=getIntent().getExtras().getString("json");
```

Comment: So if i send the whole JsonObject in the other activity how can i create a for() and use the exercise data on a dynamically created textview assuming i know the number of the exercises. I would like to know only the code snippet tha gives me access to each exercise data(name,gif,place,muscle_team)

Comment: are you asking for help in parsing json data?

Comment: Not exactly i just want to know how to write the for() and show each exercise data.

Comment: @ArisRoumeliotis consider accepting this answer as your problem has been solved